# How do I read Files with similar names in c++

Tags: c++

total1_0831.txt

total2_0831.txt

total3_0831.txt

total1_0901.txt

total2_0901.txt

I want to load 3 0831 text files

my code is

```
fstream myTxT;
myTxT.open("total1_0831.txt");

fstream myTxT;
myTxT.open("total2_0831.txt");

fstream myTxT;
myTxT.open("total3_0831.txt");
```

It was ineffective, so I wrote the code in a new way.

```
vector<fstream> myTxT;
myTxT.open("total%d_0831.txt") // i think this part is error, but i don't know how to fix it
```

This code wasn't work anymore.

Any advice would be appreciated

Comment: it should work if you have a file named `"total%d_0831.txt"`

Comment: you can setup a loop to build a string with the appropriate number for each file name. But for three files that's overkill IMO. What you already have is fine.

Comment: You are looking for [sprintf](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf) with a loop going from 1 to 3.

Comment: You mean that the first one is too much code? Or that it did not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a base string, to which you then append the number of the file to read as a string, and finally append the extension.

Once you have the path string constructed, you can load the file.

All this logic should go in a loop, and you're done!

Having said that, it probably is an overkill for just 3 files, but it's a nice method when dealing with multiple files that share a logic in their naming.